# OData / WCF Service Operation - property access through URI?

Tags: wcf, uri, odata

I use a Service Operation in WCF data service to get a object.

```
[WebGet]
    public IQueryable<sample> GetSamples(int Id)
```

I can retrieve data by

```
http://localhost:xx/GetSamples?Id=9
```

Is it possible to get property of the returned object similar to

```
http://localhost:xx/samples(x)/property
```

I've tried     http://localhost:xx/GetSamples?Id=9/property, and     http://localhost:xx/GetSamples/property?Id=9 etc. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Sample is a complex type then this won't work.
If Sample is an entity type, then it will work with a small modification. Property access is only possible on a singleton result. WCF DS doesn't know that your service operation always returns a single entity, to tell is to, add an attribute SingleResult to your service operation method. Then the first URL should work: service/GetSample/PropertyName?id=2
If the Sample is an entity type and you know the key property value (or values) then service/Samples(keypropertyvalue)/PropertyName should also work.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a select?

```
http://localhost:xx/GetSamples?Id=9&$select=property
```